# Toggle Explorer Bar

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know that `cmd+b` toggles the side bar. I know that `cmd+shift+e` shows the explorer bar. I want one command to toggle, not show, toggle, ONLY the explorer bar. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shortcuts for Windows. Change <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to <kbd>Cmd</kbd> for mac:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+e",
    "command": "-workbench.view.explorer"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+e",
    "command": "workbench.view.explorer",
    "when": "!explorerViewletVisible"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+e",
    "command": "workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility",
    "when": "explorerViewletVisible"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Open user > keybindings.json
add the following code: (it will toggle Explorer window on pressing CMD+1)

```json
    {
        "key": "cmd+1",
        "command": "workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility"
    },
```